# Facebook API - How to obtain private group event attendees?

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible, through any means, to query the Facebook API to return a list of attendees for a private group event?

I would expect that an admin of the group user token or an app(token) added to the group would be required.

Any ideas?

Reading thus far, I suspect the above is not possible at all in any way.
There used to be an API endpoint for this, however it has been removed:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v15.0/event/attending

The Graph API for Events has no way of accessing the users that are attending, only the count.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/

Answer (score 0):

Via the Facebook API - this is not possible, however I found a "work around".

1. Use selenium to auto login to Facebook as a group admin user(good idea to create a dedicated user for this with a long strong password). Store creds securely.
2. Pull back the eventId you need via the facebook API
3. Good idea to run selenium chrome driver headless
4. Setup chrome download directory to a known location
5. Navigate to "https://www.facebook.com/events/report/?eid={eventId}"
6. A csv is auto downloaded with Name and Status of all event attendees

A bit hacky hack - but it works.

I understand Facebook should lock down their API, but an app API account should be able to access this info if added to the group.